# Filter Section in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating report in SAP crystal report 2013. In SSRS their is a separate section for filter parameters. Can I have that sort of Search Criteria section in crystal report. Basically I want to provide the date and other inputs and clicking "Refresh" button it should fetch data from the database according to the inputs provided. Can someone please suggest some link/documentation on how to add a filter area in a report.

Comment: You have to use parameter fields.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly said by @Arvo you need to use parameter fields but most important you need to use those parameters in `Record Selection Formula` to retrive the required data. This will make sure that selected data is only retrived by that performance increases

For E.g create a parameter ID and now to to record selection formula by `Report -> selection formulas -> record` and write the condition as

```
databasetable. id ={?ID}
```

Then only the required data selected through parameter will be retrived else full data will be retrived from database